# Strings in processing

Tags: string, list, iteration, processing

```
    String d = "word";
    for (int j = 0; j < 22; j++) {
       String item = inventory.get(j);
       textSize(25);
       fill(255,0,255);
         if (item != d){
         text(item,w,h);
       }
    }
```

It's not recognizing d and still putting it with the text.

It's Processing. 
item is a string list that I'm trying to iterate over. I want all the words in the list except for d which is "word" to be displayed as text on the screen.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify the problem. "Not recognizing d?" d doesn't get recognised as a variable or the contents of the variable is not recognised? And is this C#? What is intended function of the code? Take time to explain a bit and you'll get better answers.

Comment: Cool, I tried to edit it to add a lil more details.

Comment: What language is this? And what is "inventory"? "item" seems to be a string, not a string list.

Comment: The language is called processing. It's like Java and C++
whoops my bad.
StringList inventory;
inventory is the string list.
item is inventory.get(j) the jth thing in inventory.

Comment: Aha, I read it as "string processing" :-) I don't know then. But maybe you could look to see if there is a string comparison function you can use instead of `!=` ?

Comment: lol Thanks. I wish processing was more like python when handling strings.

Comment: Then you should use pyprocessing or python mode in your Processing IDE :)

Answer (score 2):

try whit `!d.equals(item)` instead. it's better to compare classes whit this kind of method.

Regards
Jose

Comment: It's not just better, it's a completely different kind of comparison. != is comparing whether or not the two references are pointing towards the same object and .equals compares the contents of the two references. I feel like this should be made clear so this mistake isn't made again in the future.